# How to get microsecond from now() in Erlang

Tags: multithreading, erlang

I try to match the corresponding thread with the timestamp (microsecond from now function), just like *jill received intro message from john [739000]* *and john received reply message from jill [739000]*

```
if
     I == true ->
         M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received intro message from ", Process_name , "[",erlang:now(),"]"]), self()},
         %io:fwrite(I),
         whereis(Process_name)!{Self_name, "reply",self()},
         friends(Msg, M_pid, State + 1, Self_name);
     R == true ->
         M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received reply message from ", Process_name , "[",pid_to_list(Process_id),"]"]), self()},
         friends(Msg, M_pid, State + 1, Self_name)
 end
```

I tried to change from `process_id` to microsecond from `now()`.
I am a newbie to Erlang. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`erlang:now()` is deprecated and should NOT be used. There are two options to get current time in microseconds

1. `os:timestamp()`

```erlang
{Mega, Sec, Micro} = os:timestamp(),
(Mega * 1000000 + Sec) * 1000000 + Micro.
```

2. `os:system_time(microseconds)`